# ICCube reporting Google maps setup

Tags: google-maps, reporting, iccube

How to configure icCube so it can show Google maps widget. I can not find the guide in documentation, nor the option in the application itself.. I am familiar with using google maps api with for example JS, but how to do it in icCube? Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

###### V8 version

The documentation for icCube v8+ Google maps can be found here: https://livedemo.iccube.com/icCube/report/help?ic3demo=&ic3topic=widgets.Maps&ic3locale=en

You need to setup a google maps API key and activate it on the ic3report-config.js file:
https://livedemo.iccube.com/icCube/report/help?ic3demo=&ic3topic=gettingstarted.Configuration&ic3locale=en

```
options.google = {
    region: "",
    key: "...",
    renderedDelayMS: 1000,
}
```

---

###### V7 version

IcCube supports two types of google map: HeatingMap and RegionMap. Heating map requires longitude, latitude and heating strength measures as a columns and iterable thing on rows. Regions map requires identifier of the region according to ISO and value column. I've created an example report with map on the demo server:

https://demo6.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report?ic3demo&name=%2Fshared%2FStackOverflow%2FGoogle%20Region%20Widget%20With%20Data&menu=on

https://demo6.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report?ic3demo&name=%2Fshared%2FStackOverflow%2FGoogle%20Heatmap%20Widget%20With%20Data&menu=on

Also you'll need to setup a google maps API key. To do so, you could put a configuration option to the admin -> report config JS:

```
function ic3config(options) {
  options.googleMapApiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
}
```

[edit] This file can be accessed via the Admin / Docs console as shown in the picture attached.

[image]